# Как расположить абсолютный элемент по центру родительского?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть меню, в котором при наведении на элемент, содержащий выпадающий список,  должен появляться по центру треугольничек, который абсолютно спозиционирован относительно родительского. 
[image: картинка]
Вопрос: как разместить этот треугольник ровно по центру для любого по ширине пункта одинаково во всех браузерах (задать left в процентах не предлагать!) ? Сейчас он расположен со смещением относительно центра. [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/nso3ptcr/)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav {
  background-color: #000;
  min-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav>li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.dropdown-menu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  overflow: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-nav>li:hover {
  background-color: #ffd900;
}
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown:hover {
  position: relative;
}
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 13px 16px 0 16px;
  border-color: #ffd900 transparent transparent transparent;
  line-height: 0;
  _border-color: #ffd900 #000000 #000000 #000000;
  _filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav top-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Главная</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">О нас</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">О нас</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Контакты</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Полезное</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  margin:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Нужно лишь добавить `margin: 0` и все будет по центру

```
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown:hover:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 13px 16px 0 16px;
  border-color: #ffd900 transparent transparent transparent;
  line-height: 0;
  _border-color: #ffd900 #000000 #000000 #000000;
  _filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

И тут добавить `left: 0; right: 0, margin:0 auto;`

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` - это центрирование, а `margin: 0` - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy забыл добавить text-aling: center;

Comment: А `text-aling: center` с absolute'ом без текста - уже не очень кроссбраузерно.

Comment: @Qwertiy `margin: 0;` исключительно убрать отступ `ul` списка, а `text-align: center;` центрировать текст, плохая кроссбраузерность?

Comment: Тьфу.. Я несколько запутался. Я думал, absolute inline-block центрируется через text-align, а у тебя всё-таки margin: 0 auto.

Answer (score 1):

добавить для `.navbar-nav>li.dropdown:hover:after`

```
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown:hover:after{
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
}
```

Comment: не нравится мне такой вариант с `left: 50%; margin-left: -16px;` - вы уверены, что это будет кроссбраузерно, адаптивно и замене, к примеру шрифта или увеличении его не кегель ничего не сдвинется?

Comment: @Вася да уверен - это кроссбраузерный вариант, также шрифт не играет роли   в данном случае

Comment: и все же я доверяю, когда сам браузер высчитывает, а не сам определяешь на глаз. стоит захотеть поиграться с размерами треугольника и уже каждый раз придется его попиксельно двигать-смотреть, не криво ли расположен

Comment: расчет для margin-left = -(width triangle/2);

Answer (score 1):

Смещение происходит на половину ширины треугольника. Вернуть "на место" можно добавив вот это

```
.navbar-nav>li.dropdown:hover:after {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

PS. Для устаревших версий браузеров потребуются префиксы

Comment: а для совсем устаревших (ie8) это, к сожалению, не сработает..

Comment: @Вася Это да, но я бы на него не расчитывал

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример:

```
 ..li > a:after {
    content: "";
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0px solid #ffffff;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
```

За расположение по центру отвечает эта часть: margin: 0 auto;
Надеюсь поможет этот пример!

Comment: да, полезный, но не полный - вверху самый верный ответ